# RxJava: closing a resource after every subscriber handled it

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new to RxJava and I'm struggling to figure out how to close resources correctly, especially when dealing with multiple subscribers.

I have an `Observable<T>` where `T` is some [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) resource (e.g. say an Android database [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).

I may have multiple subscribers on the observable. I want to `close()` the resource after each subscriber is done handling it. In other words, close the old resource after the new resource has been delivered/emitted, and also finally close the last one when the last subscriber unsubscribes.

I've tried to make it work using a custom Operator that I called `AutoCloseOperator`, and it's almost working, but not quite right. I.e. I'm still race conditions and/or leaks, e.g. resources not getting closed.

What is the correct way to do this in RxJava?

Say I've got this code:

```
final AutoCloseOperator<MyResource> autoClose = new AutoCloseOperator<MyResource>();
Subject<MyResource, MyResource> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<MyResource> o = subject.lift(autoClose);

Subscription s1 = o.subscribe(new Action1<MyResource>() {
    public void call(MyResource myObj) {
        System.out.println("s1 handling " + myObj);
    }
});

subject.onNext(new MyResource(1));
subject.onNext(new MyResource(2)); // This should close Resource #1 after Resource #2 is delivered

Subscription s2 = o.subscribe(new Action1<MyResource>() {
    public void call(MyResource myObj) {
        System.out.println("s2 handling " + myObj);
    }
});

subject.onNext(new MyResource(3));
subject.onNext(new MyResource(4));

s1.unsubscribe();

subject.onNext(new MyResource(5));
subject.onNext(new MyResource(6));

s2.unsubscribe();

subject.onNext(new MyResource(7));
subject.onNext(new MyResource(8));
```

Then I'd expect the following behavior:

```
s1 handling Resource #1
s1 handling Resource #2
Closing Resource #1
s1 handling Resource #3
Closing Resource #2
s2 handling Resource #3
s1 handling Resource #4
s2 handling Resource #4
Closing Resource #3
s2 handling Resource #5
Closing Resource #4
s2 handling Resource #6
Closing Resource #5
Closing Resource #6
Closing Resource #7
Closing Resource #8
```

Note: I don't use `PublishSubject` in my real code, I just use it here for illustration purposes, I use `Observable.create` which emits a `Cursor` every time a database table is updated...

To generalize the problem: I could just use `doOnNext` and `doOnUnsubscribe` to close the old item, but that doesn't take into account that these events will happen multiple times (for each subscriber), and I only want to close the resource when all the subscribers have received the new item.

Is a custom operator using `lift()` the way to go, or is there some existing operator(s) that might help with this?

I've reduced my problem to a small command-line app [here on GitHub](https://github.com/glombard/so/tree/master/31932871_rxjava_close_resources). Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 6):

`Observable.using()` is what you need.

If you have `t` of type `T` which has a `.close()` method and you want to extract something from `t` (your cursor) say `Observable<R>` then here is how to do it:

```
Func0<T> resourceFactory = () -> t;
Func1<T, Observable<R>> observableFactory = x -> ...
Action1<T> disposeAction = x -> x.close();

Observable<R> results = Observable.using(resourceFactory, observableFactory, disposeAction);
```

You mentioned you have `Observable<T>`. To get all the Rs from all Ts then use the above code like so:

```
Observable<T> source = ...
Observable<R> results = 
    source.flatMap(t -> {
        Func0<T> resourceFactory = () -> t;
        Func1<T, Observable<R>> observableFactory = x -> ...
        Action1<T> disposeAction = x -> x.close();
        return Observable.using(resourceFactory, observableFactory, disposeAction);});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried `Observable.using()` but I'm having difficulties applying to my problem without having resources closed prematurely. When I've got more time I'll try it again and provide feedback with sample code! Thanks!

Comment: No worries. You can't let your resources bleed outside of the observableFactory otherwise you will have premature closure problems. Extract what you need from the resource and map it to something that is decoupled from the resource.